# CheXnet model training and validation loss stuck

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am training a CheXnet like model from scratch. I followed paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05225.pdf) and built the model similar. But I am unable to train it, during end-to-end training the training and validation loss get stuck at 0.1325 and
0.1489 respectively.

Current model specifications:

- DenseNet121 (+ FC layer of 14 units), ImageNet weights, end-to-end
  training
- Unweighted binary crossentropy loss
- Adam optimiser(lr=0.001), Learning rate decay of 0.1 if validation loss did not
  improve for 2 continuous epochs

I have tried changing the batch size but no luck. Can someone please help me figure out what should I change.

Thanks.